# Can supplements affect DNA? (Could 10,000% Methylcobalamin affect MTHFR genotype)

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, dna-sequencing, nutrition, epigenetics

Originally titled "Could B12 supplementation affect dna test results for B12 need?" - B12 just seems like a good example question to frame the more general question of "Can supplements affect DNA?"

I recently got a DNA test done from DNAFit and found out I do *not* have a raised need for B12 - however - I've been supplementing with about 10,000% B12 (as methylcobalamin) for quite some time now. Been taking 10,000% every day for 5 months and like 1,000+% B12 for another 5.5 months before the increased dosage. I actually am quite dependent on my supplements, and think it's quite possible that my DNA has adapted to them, if DNA does such things. (Just looking briefly, it appears there is some disagreement as to whether DNA can change due to supplementation: [google.com/search?q=CAN+SUPPLEMENTS+CHANGE+DNA](https://www.google.com/search?q=can%20supplements%20change%20dna) )

So there's the root of the question - can supplements affect DNA - more specifically - could B12 supplementation affect the result of my MTHFR genotype (which is CC, just FTR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the DNAfit test does is analyse some of your genes for common variants (called SNPs - single nucleotide polymorphisms). These are hard-written in your genetic code, they won't ever change (you could in theory have mutations in some individual cells, but we can ignore that).

Taking supplements or any other environmental influences will therefore not affect these tests.

The environment can affect certain markers *on the* DNA, that control how active a given gene is (how strong its expressed) - this is called [epigenetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics). Since these markers are written on the DNA they are also potentially heritable and the two effects (the genetic code itself and the markers on it) are often thrown into one pot when some news report about 'changes to your DNA'.